# I can't think of a condition to increase the decrement in Gradually Decreasing Carousel app

Tags: java, oop

`Decrementing Carousel` is a container, accepting int elements. `DecrementingCarousel` has a maximum capacity, specified via the constructor. When created, DecrementingCarousel is in accumulating state: you may add elements via the `addElement` method and can produce a `CarouselRun` object via the `run` method. Once the `run` method is called, `DecrementingCarousel` is in running state: it refuses adding more elements.

The `CarouselRun` allows to iterate over elements of the carousel decrementing them one by one with the `next` method. The `next` returns the value of the current element.

The `CarouselRun` iterates over elements in the order of their insertion.
When an element is decreased to zero, the `CarouselRun` will skip it in further iterations. When there are no more elements available for decrementing, the `CarouselRun` returns -1.

The `CarouselRun` also has the `isFinished` method, which indicates, if the carousel has run out of the lements to decrement.

***Specification Details***

`boolean addElement(int element)` - adds an element. If element is negative or zero, do not add the element. If container is full, do not add the element. If the run method was called to create a `CarouselRun`, do not add the element. If element is added successfully, return `true`. Return `false` otherwise.
`CarouselRun run()` - returns a CarouselRun to iterate over the elements. If the run method has already been called earlier, it must return `null`: `DecrementingCarousel` may generate only one `CarouselRun` object.

*`CarouselRun` has two public methods:*

`int next()` - returns the current value of the current element, then decreases the current element by one and switches to the next element in insertion order. Skips zero elements. When there is no more elements to decrease, returns -1.
`boolean isFinished()` - when there is no more elements to decrease, returns `true`. Otherwise, returns `false`.
**The code:**

```
public class DecrementingCarousel {
    private final int capacity;
    static int[] carousel;
    int index;
    boolean isRun;

    {
        index = 0;
        isRun = false;
    }

    public DecrementingCarousel(int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
        carousel = new int[capacity];
    }

    public boolean addElement(int element){
        if (element > 0 && index < capacity && !isRun) {
            carousel[index++] = element;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public CarouselRun run() {
        if (!isRun) {
            isRun = true;
            return new CarouselRun();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Methods in CarouselRun:

```
public class CarouselRun {
    protected final int[] array = DecrementingCarousel.carousel.clone();
    protected int position = 0;

    public int next() {
        if (isFinished())
            return -1;
        else {
            while (array[position %= array.length] <= 0) {
                position++;
            }
        }
        return array[position++]--;
    }

    public boolean isFinished() {
        for (int el : array)
            if (el > 0)
                return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

So this subclass must decrement elements by gradually increasing decrement. When you need to decrement an element for the first time, decrease it by 1. Next time you need to decrement the same element, decrease it by 2. Next time decrease by 3, then by 4 and so on.

```
public class GraduallyDecreasingCarousel extends DecrementingCarousel{
    public GraduallyDecreasingCarousel(final int capacity) {
        super(capacity);
    }

    @Override
    public CarouselRun run() {
        if (!isRun) {
            isRun = true;
            return new GraduallyDecreasingCarouselRun();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

```
public class GraduallyDecreasingCarouselRun extends CarouselRun {
    int decrement = 1;

    @Override
    public int next() {
        int beforeDecreasing;
        if (isFinished())
            return -1;
        else {
            while (array[position %= array.length] <= 0) {
                position++;
                if (position == array.length) {
                    decrement++;
                }
            }
        }
        beforeDecreasing = array[position];
        array[position++] -= decrement;
        return beforeDecreasing;
    }
```

The main method:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DecrementingCarousel carousel = new GraduallyDecreasingCarousel(7);

        carousel.addElement(20);
        carousel.addElement(30);
        carousel.addElement(10);

        CarouselRun run = carousel.run();

        System.out.println(run.isFinished()); //false

        System.out.println(run.next()); //20
        System.out.println(run.next()); //30
        System.out.println(run.next()); //10

        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>");

        System.out.println(run.next()); //19
        System.out.println(run.next()); //29
        System.out.println(run.next()); //9

        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>");

        System.out.println(run.next()); //17
        System.out.println(run.next()); //27
        System.out.println(run.next()); //7

        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>");

        System.out.println(run.next()); //14
        System.out.println(run.next()); //24
        System.out.println(run.next()); //4

        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>");

        System.out.println(run.next()); //10
        System.out.println(run.next()); //20

        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>");

        System.out.println(run.next()); //5
        System.out.println(run.next()); //15

        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>");

        System.out.println(run.next()); //9

        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>");

        System.out.println(run.next()); //2

        System.out.println(run.isFinished()); //true
        System.out.println(run.next()); //-1
    }
}
```

it works fine in main but wont pass the tests
IDK how to change next method in GraduallyDecreasingCarouselRun

tried counting next calls and reset the counter when its greater than amount of elements to decrease but when theres one element left its wasnt working correctly

Comment: Did I understand the problem correctly: in the first instance of `GraduallyDecreasingCarouselRun` the values of `array` should be decreased by 1 each run, in the second instance they should be decreased by 2 etc...?

Comment: Also what I don't understand: you give a *capacity* to the carousel, but in your test you don't fill it completely. From other collections I would expect that they never give back more values than added, independently of their capacity. Why do you add only 3 items in your test, but then call `run.next()` 19 times? This is not an expectable behaviour.
I don't even understand the implementation and expected behaviour of `DecrementingCarousel` and its `CarouselRun` class.

Comment: @cyberbrain yeah you got it rigth. it doesnt matter how much elements was added if its < 1 it will be ignored. `DecrementingCarouse` works basiclly the same as but its always decrementing by 1

Comment: Was the initial implementation (of `DecrementingCarousel` and `CarouselRun` also written by you? I still would need the answers to my second comment ("Also what I don't understand...") because the whole parent implementation doesn't fit to your description for me.

Comment: @cyberbrain yes. I edited the description maybe it will be more clear.

Comment: OK, I think after an hour of debugging I understood the requirements and the code. So far it looks correct, also if I modify your main method into a junit test, everything runs OK. So what exactly do you mean with "it works fine in main but wont pass the tests"? I don't find any error, all the values you printed to be expected are returned.

Comment: @cyberbrain [tests](https://www.codepile.net/pile/9j6K6mE8) majority of tests wont pass

Comment: and these [tests](https://www.codepile.net/pile/EnxYM8Rx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow. Needed a really long time to fully understand the problem.
The problem occurs when you fill the capacity of your array completely.

In that case your check for incrementing the value of `decrease` inside the while loop can fail, because the modulo assignment will "reset" the position to 0 without going inside the loop and therefore skipping the increment of `decrease`.

The solution to make the code understandable easier would be to decouple the modulo assignment from the while condition. This is slower and uses more code, but makes it easier to understand and also handles `position` as the "next" position like stated in the specification. Optimizations are possible, but I just post the unoptimized code here:

```java
public int next() {
    int beforeDecreasing;
    if (isFinished())
        return -1;
    else {
        beforeDecreasing = array[position];
        array[position] -= decrement;
        do {
            position++;
            if (position == array.length) {
                decrement++;
                position = 0;
            }
        } while ((array[position] <= 0) && !isFinished());
    }
    return beforeDecreasing;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

/** Hello! I provide fully working code for this exercise. I write all classes here in one file for ease of reading, but in reality I have everything separated from each other. Therefore, in order to pass all the tests correctly, I advise you to take each class separately */

```
public class CarouselRun  {
public int [] carousel = DecrementingCarousel.carousel;
public int capacity;
int index;

public CarouselRun() {

}
public int next() {
    if (isFinished())
        return -1;
    else {
        while (!isFinished() && carousel[index %= carousel.length] <= 0) {
            index++;
        }
    }
    return carousel[index++]--;
}

public boolean isFinished() {
    for (int el : carousel)
        if (el > 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

}

```
public class DecrementingCarousel extends CarouselRun {
public static int[] carousel;
static int countElement;
boolean isRun;

public DecrementingCarousel(final int capacity) {
    this.capacity = capacity;
    carousel = new int[capacity];

}

public DecrementingCarousel() {
}

public CarouselRun run() {
    if (!isRun) {
        isRun = true;
        return new DecrementingCarousel();
    }
    return null;
}

public boolean addElement(int element) {
    if (element > 0 && index < carousel.length && !isRun) {
        carousel[index++] = element;
        countElement++;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}`

```
public class GraduallyDecreasingCarousel extends DecrementingCarousel {

int decrement = 1;

public GraduallyDecreasingCarousel(final int capacity) {
    super(capacity);
}

public GraduallyDecreasingCarousel() {

}

@Override
public CarouselRun run() {
    if (!isRun) {
        isRun = true;
        return new GraduallyDecreasingCarousel();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int next() {
    if (isFinished()) {
        return -1;
    } else {

        while (carousel[index %= carousel.length] <= 0) {
            index++;
            if (index == carousel.length) {
                decrement++;
            }
        }
    }

    int value = carousel[index];
    carousel[index++] -= decrement;

    if (index == carousel.length) {
        decrement++;
    }

    return value;
}

@Override
public boolean isFinished() {
    return super.isFinished();
}
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Andrii : Could you please explain in short how does your code works? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For a "quick win" I would suggest another solution: change the place and check for the increment of `decrease`: (only snippet from inside the `else` branch)

```java
int oldPosition = position;
while (array[position %= array.length] <= 0) {
    position++;
}
if (oldPosition > position) {
    decrement++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most complicated question, in this exercise is how to track the index of the carousel. I recommend decoupling index tracking from next() method. Such feature should be based on storing the values of both "old decrement position" and "new decrement position". This way, you can control better, when to decrease "decrement" variable from -1 to -2 (and program knows what to do in case the next value in the array is equal to 0). In the presented solution, index tracking feature is introduced by calculateNewIndexDecrementPosition() method. I also show next() and isFinished() methods to make the whole CarouselRun class implementation clearer.

```
    private int calculateNewIndexDecrementPosition(int currentIndexDecrementPostion) {
        int newIndexDecrementPosition;

//If no more elements to decrease are present. Meaning the situation where there are only zeroes in the array.
        if (elementsToDecreaseWhileRunning == 0) {
//Basically get out. Could be any other value in return statement.
            return 0;
        }
//If you reached end of the array, go back to the beginning (0 index). THIS IS THE PLACE WHERE YOU DECREASE THE VALUE FROM -1 TO -2, -2 T0 -3 AND SO ON...
        if (karuzel.size() - 1 == currentIndexDecrementPostion) {
            newIndexDecrementPosition = 0;
            this.amountToDecrease -= 1;
        } else {
//otherwise go through the elements in the increasing order
            newIndexDecrementPosition = currentIndexDecrementPostion + 1;
        }
//If the value of the next element in the array also equals zero, call the function again to recalculate (increment) the index.
        if (karuzel.get(newIndexDecrementPosition) == 0) {
            newIndexDecrementPosition = calculateNewIndexDecrementPosition(newIndexDecrementPosition);
        }
        return newIndexDecrementPosition;
    }



       public int next() {
//The value of elementsToDecreaseWhileRunning comes from the addElement(int element) method, which was defined in CarouselRun Class in the following way. Every time the new element has been added to the carousel the method increases ElementsToDecrease while running by one: carouselRun.setElementsToDecreaseWhileRunning(carouselRun.getElementsToDecreaseWhileRunning() + 1).
//The variable "elementsToDecreaseWhileRunning" stores the information about how many positive numbers are still in the array. The total amount of positive numbers in the array, allows to control when to stop the whole process of decrementing.
//If ElementsToDecreaseWhileRunning equals zero, it means that all the elements in the array were brought to value zero.
        if (karuzel.isEmpty() || elementsToDecreaseWhileRunning == 0) {
            return -1;
        }

        int oldValue = karuzel.get(currentIndexDecrementPostion);

//"newValue" initialization;
        int newValue = 0;

        if (typeOfCarousel.equals("decrementing")) {
            newValue = karuzel.get(currentIndexDecrementPostion) - 1;
        } else if (typeOfCarousel.equals("gradually")) {
            newValue = karuzel.get(currentIndexDecrementPostion) + this.amountToDecrease;

//Protects against undesired, negative values in the carousel
            if (newValue < 0) {
                newValue = 0;
            }
        }
        karuzel.set(currentIndexDecrementPostion, newValue);

//The value of elementsToDecreaseWhileRunning comes from the addElement(int element) method, which was defined in CarouselRun Class in the following way. Every time the new element has been added to the carousel, counter ElementsToDecrese increases: carouselRun.setElementsToDecreaseWhileRunning(carouselRun.getElementsToDecreaseWhileRunning() + 1);
//If new value equals zero, the value of "iteration until the end" (elementsToDecreaseWhileRunning) is decreased by one. It means that, there's one less positive element in the array. The total amount of positive numbers in the array, allows to control when to stop the whole process of decrementing.
        if (newValue == 0) {
            elementsToDecreaseWhileRunning--;
        }
 //Index tracking feature
        this.currentIndexDecrementPostion = calculateNewIndexDecrementPosition(this.currentIndexDecrementPostion);

//next() based on the instructions should return value of the current element
        return oldValue;
    }
      public boolean isFinished() {
            return this.elementsToDecreaseWhileRunning <= 0;
        }
```

I added  comments to almost each line of code, because I'm aware that the exercise comes from the Java Training Program, which accepts also beginning programmers. I hope that this way the solution might be understood by everyone.